# Map inside map in java

Tags: java

What is wrong with this instantiation :

```
Map<String, String, HashMap<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String, String, HashMap<String,String>>();
```

Comment: (You might want to consider declaring it with `Map` instead of `HashMap`: `Map<String,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String, String,Map<String,String>>();`. Also you might want to introduce an object that represents a composite key so you only need one map.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A [`Map<K,V>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is a mapping from keys of type `K` to values of type `V`. There are only 2 type parameters to a map.

You attempted to define a map with 3 type parameters; this is not possible, and has nothing to do with the fact that you're putting a `Map` inside a `Map`.

A `Map<K1,Map<K2,V2>>` works just fine.

A `Map<X,Y,Z>` does not.

It's possible that you need something like `Map< Pair<L,R>, Map<K,V> >`. Java does not have generic `Pair<L,R>` type, but see related questions below for solutions.

#### Related questions

On pairs/tuples:

- [What is the equivalent of the C++ `Pair<L,R>` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)
- [Java generics `Pair<String, String>` stored in `HashMap` not retrieving key->value properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779414/java-generics-pairstring-string-stored-in-hashmap-not-retrieving-key-value-pr)
- [A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)
- [Does Java need tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457775/does-java-need-tuples)
- [How to return multiple objects from a Java method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457629/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-a-java-method)

On nested maps:

- [Java: Spring Framework: Declaring Nested Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963599/java-spring-framework-declaring-nested-maps)
- [Java: How do you declare nested map in spring framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957407/java-how-do-you-declare-nested-map-in-spring-framework)
- [Map of Maps data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093718/map-of-maps-data-structure)

Comment: I'm trying to create method to create XML element, where element name and value are in one hashmap, and attributes and values of those attributes in other hashmap, do you think it is a good idea, or pass 4 arraylists to a method each containing only elem names, values, attributes, attribute values

Comment: but I guess the problem is that hashmap doesn't allow duplicates, where duplicates can be node name with different values or attributes

Comment: @London: to be precise, _any_ `Map` can only map one key to one value. The same value can be mapped by several keys, i.e. it's a many-to-one relation, not one-to-many, and not one-to-one. You can define a `Map<K,Set<V>>` to emulate mapping a key to several values (or better yet, use Guava's Multimap), but I'm still not sure what you're doing to actually give any advice. You may want to ask another question where you clearly specify what is it that you're doing.

Comment: actually there is a generic pair implementation, though it is not so popular. See SimpleEntry (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html). My life changed since I discovered it :)

Comment: @Eyal Schneider There are OOD arguments against a generic Pair class in Java. See this good post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java

Comment: @Paul Jackson: I agree with the OOD arguments. Actually the class I mentioned can be used as a generic pair, but it has a more specific semantics: key-value relationship. So I agree that it shouldn't be used unless this is the actual relationship.

Answer (score 5):

Maps only have 2 type parameters, you have 3 (in your "outer" Map).

Answer (score 5):

Map interface (as well as HashMap class) expects only 2 generic type arguments: one for the key type and one for the value type. You provide 3...

Answer (score 1):

If you wish you can use something of this kind

```
Map<Object,Map<String,String>>
```

This object can be an object of a Class holding two Strings.
Hope this solves your problem.

```
Class Xyz {
String s1;
String s2;
}
```

An object of Xyz can be used as key in the above map.